# Javascript- Convert Dictionary into List of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I currently have data structued as

```
{ 
  {id: 
    {prop: value}
  },
  {anotherId: 
    {prop: value}
 }
}
```

and I want to convert it into an array of objects:

```
[
   {id: 
     {prop: value}
   },
   {anotherId: 
     {prop: value}
  }
]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not sure what that screenshot is trying to communicate.  Could you edit the question to show exactly what you have, and what exactly you would like it to be instead, including the code that you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: You don't manipulate data with React--AFAICT there's nothing React or even Firebase about this question--it's just JS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, see the edited question. The answer that Anthony gave solved my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const obj = {
  a: { 1: 'something', 2: 'something else' },
  b: { 1: 'something', 2: 'something else' }
};

console.log(Object.values(obj));
```